# C# Break string into multiple parts

Tags: c#

I have the following string:

```
+53.581N -113.587W 4.0 Km W of Edmonton, AB
```

In C# is there anyway to break this string out into Long. Latt. and then city state and discare the middle part?

So basically I want 3 strings:

```
Long
Latt
Location.
```

Is this possible with multiple forms of this string? They are in the same formate but obviously the data would be different.

Thanks

Comment: Using regular expressions is probably your best best. But to formulate a concrete pattern, a few more examples of input strings would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression to accomplish this - something like:

```
string input = @"+53.581N -113.587W 4.0 Km W of Edmonton, AB";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^(?<latitude>[+\-]\d+\.\d+[NS])\s+(?<longitude>[+\-]\d+\.\d+[EW])\s+\d+\.\d+\s+Km\s+[NSEW]\s+of\s+(?<city>.*?),\s*(?<state>.*)$");
if (match.Success) {
    string lattitude = match.Groups["lattitude"].value;
    string longitude = match.Groups["longitude"].value;
    string city = match.Groups["city"].value;
    string state = match.Groups["state"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like in all languages, it's possible with the power of the oh-so-awesome Regular Expressions.

If you are unfamiliar with Regular Expressions, I suggest you learn them. They're awesome. Seriously.

Here's a tutorial to get started with .NET regexps:

http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/regexlearnsyntax.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to capture those parts. See http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prasad_1/regexppsd12062005021717am/regexppsd.aspx.

A pattern that should work is the following (considering the one example you provided):

```
^([+-]\d+\.\d+\w) ([+-]\d+\.\d+\w) (.*?)$
```

Comment: +1 I would totally go regex for this one. I bet you can find some patterns to use

Comment: You can use regex and find patterns for anything. That doesn't add anything new.

Comment: Per the original question, this RegEx won't separate the City, State and discard the "middle part".

Answer (score 1):

Use the string.Split(Char[], Int32) overload

```
var input = "+53.581N -113.587W 4.0 Km W of Edmonton, AB";
var splitArray = input.Split(new char[]{' '},3);
```

You will get the Long, Lat and Location. ( note the 3 - this splits the array three times )

Response to other answers suggesting Regex:

Please avoid regex if the format is going to be the same. The above option is much more simpler and the regex tend to get incomprehensible very quickly.

Comment: I think the regex and this solution are very good.  I tend to avoid regex since it can quickly get incomprehensible.  For a very simple solution I think the String.Split works very well.  For more complicated tasks I tend to lean towards regexs.

Comment: @Justin - absolutely. But follow KISS. A complicated regex should be simple in the context of the problem.